# How to make mdstat ignore specified devices

Tags: kvm, mdadm, zfs

I have a hypervisor with KVM that uses zvols for virtual machine storage. One such virtual machine was moved from a physical one and has software RAID inside it. Zvols are detected as block devices on the hypervisor, so, the hypervisor now shows the virtual-RAID as its own.

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md123 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 zd1248p2[0]
     987904 blocks [2/1] [U_]         
md124 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 zd1248p3[0]
     4891712 blocks [2/1] [U_]
```

Is there a way to make the host ignore these devices and not show them as its own RAID?